What happens when multiple C# tasks start when another task is completed?
Let's say that I have this code:
public async void Run()
{
    TaskCompletionSource t = new TaskCompletionSource();
    Prepare(t.Task);
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    t.SetResult();
    Console.WriteLine("End");
}

public async void Prepare(Task task)
{
    await Run(task, "A");
    await Run(task, "B");
    await Run(task, "C");
    await Run(task, "D");
}

public async Task Run(Task requisite, string text)
{
    await requisite;
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}

What happens when the t.SetResult(); is called?
Is this multithread?
There is any guarantee of the order of the items in the Console?
If I have a List<>, that the Run method changes it, do I need to worry about multithread?

Stop using async void and await all your tasks, and these questions will go away.

This is a simplification of a real question... I appreciate if we focus on the response instead of the workarounds...

While you wrote a simple await statement;
await requisite;

The C# compiler moved your method to a separate class and translated that "simple" await into something equivalent to;
private Task requisite;
private int state = 0;
private void MoveNext()
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case 0:
            var awaiter = requisite.GetAwaiter();
            if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
            {
                state = 1;
                awaiter.OnCompleted(MoveNext);
                return;
            }
            goto case 1;
        case 1:
            // resume execution here when the task is complete
            break;
    }
}

As you can see, if the task was already complete, your code would continue synchronously. If the task was incomplete, a callback would be registered, to continue execution later.
The exact implementation of each awaiter can be quite different. For example Task.Yield will return an awaiter that is never complete. Forcing the continuation to execute on the thread pool.
Most task types, and all the tasks from your example, will call each continuation method synchronously while .SetResult is called.
Back to your specific example;
public async void Prepare(Task task)
{
    await Run(task, "A");
    await Run(task, "B");
    await Run(task, "C");
    await Run(task, "D");
}

On the first call to Run the task is incomplete, so Run will register a continuation Action and return an incomplete task. The first await in the Prepare method will also see that the returned task is incomplete. Though the method is void so another incomplete task is not returned.
When you resume after your delay and call t.SetResult();, first the registered continuation to resume the Run method will be called. When the Run method completes, rather than returning, .SetResult will be called on the incomplete task, causing the continuation for Prepare to be called immediately. All of this will occur in the same thread, before t.SetResult returns.
If you were to place a breakpoint in either Run or Prepare and examine the call stack, you would see how the thread stack is inverted from what you would normally expect. Each returning async function will be there, with a call to SetResult in the stack.

"Task.Yield will return an awaiter that is never complete. Forcing the continuation to execute on the thread pool." -- Actually the await Task.Yield() continues on the captured SynchronizationContext. This is its documented behavior. This is not an example suitable for this question IMHO.

The point was merely that awaiters can have different behaviour. eg I/O and other OS handles and timers. But most other tasks just execute callbacks immediately.


When SetResult() is called, the first task ("A") resumes its execution after await inside the Run(Task, string) function and prints "A". Then returns in the Prepare() to await Run(task, "B"), which will print "B". And so on. Finally the "ABCD" will be printed in order.
You can't say if it will be multithreaded or not. It will be depended on the what TaskScheduler is used in the current environment and what other tasks are executed on this scheduler. By default, you will have a thread pool containing several threads. Most likely (but without any guarantees) your tasks will be executed on different threads, but not in parallel (if we are talking about ABCD tasks).
The order of ABCD is guaranteed because you await-ing the current task before starting the next one.
About the modifying the List<> inside Run - most probably this will work, because there are no concurrent edits. At the same time this is definitely the fragile code, which may be silently broken with ease during the future code modifications. I will try to to avoid such a code as much as possible and use locks or some concurrent collection. Or at least write a long comment describing the limitations of the current implementation.


Thanks! I think I really can't use tasks to my problem... I have some parallel task, that need fast sincronization...
I think I need to manually control fragmenting the method inside many smaller methods and manually control the execution of them...

@Everton This is why it's better to explain what you're trying to achieve, rather than asking about details related to your attempted solution. You can show this as something you tried, of course, but if we knew exactly what you're doing, we could potentially suggest a solution.

Technically, if it is not mandatory to run all the tasks in parallel (which is almost impossible anyway due to the hardware limitations), then you can achieve some parallelism with Task.WhenAll() and friends instead of consecutive awaits. So, you run a bunch of tasks then waits all of them. In this case you will get as much parallelism as possible (managed by the thread pool depending on the system resources).

@EvertonElvioKoser consider accepting this answer and asking a more focused/specific question next time...

It greatly depends on throughput that applicaiton is handling - if there is high traffic, there may be multiple threads involved.
But generally, Task and using async/await does not guarantee multithreading, new threads are used (from thread pool) when they are needed - current thread is busy with some work and can't take on new work.
The idea with asynchronous execution is that when there's work that has to be waited on (our processor must wait for something, like I/O operation), it releases current thread and let's it take some other work.
This way it may be that one thread is executing two tasks "parallely". But it's multitasking rather than multithreading.
With that knowledge, let's analyze your code.
First, you create TaskCompletionSource which has Task that is "ongoing" and can be awaited - but it will complete once we call SetResult on TaskCompletionSource.
Then we call Prepare, which we do not await, but it awaits passed Task, so this path of execution will stop on await Run(task, "A") and await for the task to complete, which will happen when we call SetResult (as explained earlier). After Prepare (so the task is already being awaited), we call await Task.Delay - we have another await here, this time for the delay. As we are using Tasks, new thread won't be created, as await Run is just awaiting, the thread can continue with other work and will process execution of your code. So awaiting for the delay and for the task will be done in parallel, asynchronously.
Then, when the delay is complete, it will set the result of the task, meaning await Run(task, "A") will get "unblocked", print the result, and continue to await Run(task, "B"), but this will try to await already completed task, and so it will execute synchronously (task already completed, nothing to await), immediately prinitng "B", then "C" and then "D" (in sequence).
One issue you may encounter - your program may finish before all tasks in Prepare method would finish - because it's async void and we have no way to await it. I would suggest small enhancement:
public async void Run()
{
    TaskCompletionSource t = new TaskCompletionSource();
    var prepareTask = Prepare(t.Task);
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    t.SetResult();
    
    await prepareTask;
    
    Console.WriteLine("End");
}

public async Task Prepare(Task task)
{
    await Run(task, "A");
    await Run(task, "B");
    await Run(task, "C");
    await Run(task, "D");
}

public async Task Run(Task requisite, string text)
{
    await requisite;
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}

